# using ModelConfiguration in Entity Framework gives an error " is not a valid property expression "

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my C# project, I get an error when EF attempts to create my database
The error occurs when I call

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDatabase>());
```

The error message is

```
The expression 'x => x.Dependancies' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.
```

My Domain classes are as follows

```
[Table("LoggedEntity")]
public class LoggedEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("TemplateTaskDependancy")]
public class TemplateTaskDependancy : LoggedEntity
{
    [Column]
    public int NeededTaskId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("TaskId")]
    public virtual TemplateTask Task { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("NeededTaskId")]
    public virtual TemplateTask NeededTask { get; set; }
}

[Table("TemplateTask")]
public class TemplateTask : LoggedEntity
{
    public ICollection<TemplateTaskDependancy> Dependancies;

    public ICollection<TemplateTaskDependancy> NeededTasks;

    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
}

[Table("Template")]
public class Template : LoggedEntity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My Configuration Class is as follows

```
public class TemplateTaskConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<TemplateTask>
{
    public TemplateTaskConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Dependancies)
            .WithRequired(d => d.Task)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.TaskId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasMany(x => x.NeededTasks)
            .WithRequired(d => d.NeededTask)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.NeededTaskId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

My Context is as follows

```
public class ApplicationDatabase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TemplateTask> TemplateTasks { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TemplateTaskDependancy> TemplateTaskDependancies { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TemplateTaskConfiguration());
    }

    public void InitializeDatabase()
    {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDatabase>());
    }
}
```

Comment: you're sure it's not supposed to be Dependencies? Instead of Dependancies?

Comment: Yes - spellcheck passes both, but I have only used Dependancies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite literally, the problem is what is described. `Dependancies` is a field, not a property. Just define it as:

```
public virtual ICollection<TemplateTaskDependancy> Dependancies
{
     get;
     set;
}
```

And it should solve your problem.